Is it possible to have a notification from an Android application without having to launch it?
To give more context, I am currently coding an application in Android Studio using Java, which is supposed to send a notification when it receives data. However, I've only managed to make it send a notification when the application is launched, which is not what I am trying to achieve. What I am looking for is for the app to make a request every 30 minutes to receive data, and then send a notification if the data is received. Is there a solution for this ?
I tried implementing Broadcast Receivers and Services, but I don't see how to make them request data every 30 minutes.

The recommended mechanism for this is push notifications (← keyword to search) where your backend sends a message to google servers, they send a notification to the device and that wakes the app. Otherwise you would have to run a background service (← the other search keyword).

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

If what you want is to make a request to an API every 30 mins you can use Workers, to know this you can look at the documentation, it is quite simple -> https://developer.android.com/develop/background-work/background-tasks/persistent/getting-started?hl=es-419
